# Mandatory payments for new members

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civimember, civisepa

I am looking for an elegant solution for the following. It shouldn't be very difficult but I am new to CiviCRM and I want to make the right decisions.

We only have one membership option. Members pay 10,- euro per year. This membership automatically renews until it is cancelled by the member.

If someone becomes a new member, there is a 'joining fee'. A new member pays 10,- extra. So in the first year a new member pays 20,-, in the following years they pay 10,- per year.

I want to use CiviSEPA to handle the payments.

Comment: what CMS? If drupal then you could use webform and use conditionals so if a person has an existing membership they do not see/pay the initial $10

Comment: Oh sorry, I use Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution really depends on having a reliable way to detect that someone is an existing member.  However, assuming you have such a method (e.g. members are logged in or can be detected via unsupervised dedupe rules), I would recommend using CiviDiscount to apply an [automatic discount based on membership status](https://docs.civicrm.org/discount/en/latest/autodiscount/).

Comment: I think that a modification to the form is not what I am looking for. Because everyone who registers through the form will be a new member.

(The membership automatically renews, and I don't expect members to come back after they ended their membership. If that last (very unusual) thing happens it wouldnt be a problem to fix that manually).

The only thing I need is that a membership costs 20,- in the first year and 10,- in every following year. Or is this also something that I can do with CiviDiscount?